# Get default image directory with styles large?

Tags: files

My images are saved in folder

```
sites/all/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image
```

But to make this future save i dont want to hardwire the path? Is there a drupal function to get the images in a proper way? 
I played around with

```
image_style_url(uri)
```

But i just need the default dir to pass it to javascript, I dont have image uris yet...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will get you exactly what you want, but the 'default' path is just `public://`, so.

```
$url = image_style_url('large', 'public://');
```

will return

```
http://yoursite.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public
```

I think it's more likely you're looking for a specific path, e.g.

```
$url = image_style_url('large', 'public://field/image');
```

which returns

```
http://yoursite.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image
```